# Is there a FTP plugin For Eclipse Che?

Tags: eclipse-che

So I am not sure if this is an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, but figured no better place to ask than where dev's come together...

Does anyone know if there is a FTP plugin for Eclipse Che?
I love the whole online coding thing, especially since we work several people together on the same project at a time. but uploading, and downloading (as in nedbeans) has become a must... And now it's proving to be quite a pain...

Anyone know of some way to get it running?

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, there is not FTP plugin for eclipse-che, however, there is support for ssh connection and it gives you the flexibility to mount your workspace to anywhere you want and you can still use your local favorite IDE to make changes in your code,

In order to achieve that;

**# On Linux & Mac - first install sshfs**

Open your local Terminal and execute  `sshfs user@${hostname}:/projects /your/local/directory/ -p ${port}`, where `${port}` is a random port from the ephemeral port range, to which 22 port is mapped (you can find it on the Consoles panel > SSH or at the Operations Perspective > Servers tab). This command will mount /projects folder to your local directory.

-- Windows users can use sshfs by installing free software win-sshfs for Window versions up to 7 or by purchasing software such as SFTP Net Drive for Windows 8.0, 8.1 or 10